# Dynamically inflating a fragment using layout xml, cannot find the fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to inflate a layout, which contains a fragment declared inside it. This layout is then added as a subview to a framelayout. Though the fragment gets inflated properly, i am not able to search for the fragment at all.

```
class Activity1 extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(...){
     setContentView(R.layout.container);
     mContainer = findViewId(R.id.container);
   }

   public void OnClick(...){
     LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.child, mContainer);
     Fragment f =getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
     //f is always null
  }
}

layout.container
 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" .../>

layout.child
 <fragment android:name="com.example.child" .../>
```

Am i missing something?

**I think I found the issue,**

This is in fragmentmanager code

```
View parent = null;
int containerId = parent != null ? parent.getId() : 0
fragment.mFragmentId = id != 0 ? id : containerId;
```

So I guess inflating a fragment using layout inflater does not work the same way as adding a fragment using FragmentManager

Comment: so i found something interesting, the fragment manager only gets fragments inflated this way, if they are derived from Fragment and not from ListFragment. 

So now the only bit left is that why fragments inflated this way cannot be searched using id, given the id of the container should have become the id of the framgner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give id of `<fragment />` element in java instead of its container.

Give your fragment some id inside the xml layout as below :

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/myFragment" 
          android:name="com.example.child" .../>
```

Access your fragment as below :

```
Fragment f =getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);
```

This will give you non-null fragment from the layout properly.

Comment: this solution works but was not related to what i was asking. -1 just for irrelevance to ask here

Comment: i have answered what you asked.. you have edited your question details after my answer. In that case, answerer cannot track if question is changed